# Connect to a service using TCP inside Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, twitch

I have a service written in Go that runs fine on my machine with no issues. However, when I deployed to Cloud Run, I received an EOF after connecting. Is Cloud Run blocking me from making plain TCP connections?

More context: I connect to Twitch's IRC using `tls.DialWithDialer` on "irc.chat.twitch.tv:6697" (TLS).

Is Twitch blocking Cloud Run IP addresses or Cloud Run forbidden TCP connections?

I know Cloud Run only accepts (listen) to HTTP, but I'm trying to connect, NOT listen.

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo on an environment variable. So yes, services running on Cloud Run **can** connect to other services through plain TCP/IP.